# I have an ISO 8601 week number (ex: 201801) corresponding to week 1 of 2018. What is the best way in pyth

Tags: python, datetime

I have an ISO 8601 week number, say 201801 - corresponding to week 1 of year 2018.

How do I extract the dates within the week using python?

Answer (score 0):

I would get the sunday of that week, and then give 7 days starting from that. Depending on what you want to happen in week 52, you might want to remove the `break`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def days_from_weekstr(weekstr):
    sunday = datetime.strptime(weekstr + "-0", "%Y%W-%w")
    year = sunday.year
    for i in range(7):
        day = sunday + timedelta(1) * i
        if day.year != year:
            break
        yield day.date()
```

### Usage:

```
>>> list(days_from_weekstr("201801"))
[datetime.date(2018, 1, 7), datetime.date(2018, 1, 8), datetime.date(2018, 1, 9), datetime.date(2018, 1, 10), datetime.date(2018, 1, 11), datetime.date(2018, 1, 12), datetime.date(2018, 1, 13)]
```